# How to get the exact value from pickView with multiple component

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a PickerView and a Label like this:

[image]

I want to,  when I change the value of each row in components, it will assign the value to the label above.

For example: when I choose "Blue" in the first component and "Two" in the second component it will assign "Blue Two" to the Label.

I have tried like this, but it doesn't work well, it goes crash when I select the sixth value in the second component:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var colorLabel: UILabel!
    let colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Black", "White"]
    let numbers = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four" ,"Five", "Six", "Seven"]
    var array = [[String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        array = [colors, numbers]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return array[component].count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return array[component][row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        colorLabel.text = component == 0 ? array[component][row] + " " + array[component][row] : array[component][row] + " " + array[component][row]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    var selectedValueFirstRow = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    var selectedValueSecondRow = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1)

    colorLabel.text = colors[selectedValueFirstRow] + " " + numbers[selectedValueSecondRow]
}
```

Your code is crashing because its out of index for the first array

Answer (score 0):

I add these lines in the top of ViewController

```
var colorString = ""
var numberString = ""
```

and change the didSelectRow function like this:

```
 func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if component == 0 {
            colorString = array[component][row]
        } else {
            numberString = array[component][row]
        }
        resultLabel.text = colorString + " " + numberString
    }
```

It works well now.